# How to modify search order for ALL folders

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, filesystems, sorting

what I mean by this is when you right-click in a folder, there is an option "More" By default, the only time-based sorting is Date Modified which takes very long, sometimes half a minute and from what I read is this is because it opens every file, the better alternative that I like is date created but that needs to be manually added, That's fine but it needs to be manually added for EVERY FOLDER you want it in. The solution that I looked up was to change the sorting when the files and folders are in the "details" layout but not to change it for the right-click "sort by" menu. I use the "Large Icons" layout, so that doesn't work for me. My gut tells me this will require a registry edit, but I don't know how to do so. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Where are you clicking to see "More"? I don't see it in Explorer.

Comment: When you right-click, along with all the sorting options, at the end there is a "More" button

Answer (score 0):

I question your assertion that accessing `Date Modified` is more time-consuming than accessing `Date Created`, since those, along with `Date Accessed`, are properties common to all files and not exif metadata:

```
PS Documents> (gci -af)[0] | gm -MemberType Property | ? name -match 'Time'


   TypeName: System.IO.FileInfo

Name              MemberType Definition
----              ---------- ----------
CreationTime      Property   datetime CreationTime {get;set;}
CreationTimeUtc   Property   datetime CreationTimeUtc {get;set;}
LastAccessTime    Property   datetime LastAccessTime {get;set;}
LastAccessTimeUtc Property   datetime LastAccessTimeUtc {get;set;}
LastWriteTime     Property   datetime LastWriteTime {get;set;}
LastWriteTimeUtc  Property   datetime LastWriteTimeUtc {get;set;}
```

But with that being said, the properties displayed when you right-click in a folder background and hover over `Sort by >` are determined by the columns selected for the `Details` view --- *regardless of the selected view mode*.

So, for `Date Created` to appear in the `Sort by >` context menu, you want to modify the default template for each *`FolderType`* (Generic, Documents, Music, etc.). This is done via:

- `View` Ribbon -> Options -> Change folder and search options ->
  `View` tab -> `Apply to FOlders` button.

  1. Open a folder using the *`FolderType`* you wish to modify.
  2. Select the `Details` view.
  3. Select desired columns and default sort column/direction.
  4. Switch to desired default view mode (Large iconc).
  5. Set this view as the default using `Apply to Folders` as described above.

Warning!!! The default behavior of `Apply to Folders` clears the saved views for all folders that use that *`FolderType`* so the new default is applied the next time the folder is opened. If you want to create the custom default while preserving existing views, you should export the following registry keys:

```
HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU
HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags
```

before using `Apply to folders` and then merge the exported data afterwards.

Also be aware that not all *`FolderTypes`* are available via the `Customize` tab in a folder's `Properties` dialog -- most notelably those based on location -- Downloads and the various OneDrive folders.

Here's a .zip file of folders empty except for a desktop.ini file that sets the FOlderType -- use these to set the OneDrive FolderTYpes:

[Apply to Folders RoundUp](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqkRvcFO6LtjwEQg24QOhklU1Tsz?e=1zqboc)

And use these shell commands to open system folders that have a dedicated FolderType ( Copy & paste into **Explorer** Address bar ):

- shell:Downloads
- shell:UsersFilesFolder
- shell:Searches
- shell:COntacts
- shell:UsersLibrairesFolder
- shell:AccountPictures

Comment: I got you uptil the apply for all folders but the sort by modification option isn't there, its done from the right click menu and I don't see a way to change that there. Could you please explain and tell me if I'm missing something here?

Comment: You set the active **Explorer** view to your preferred settings -- that's where you set sort and grouping, etc. ***Then*** open `Folder Options` *from the `View` ribbon* of **Explorer**, and excute `Apply to Folders` from there. `Apply to Folders` "grabs" the view settings of the Explorer window it is launched from, and makes that view the default for the current FolderType.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try [**WinSetView**](https://lesferch.github.io/WinSetView). It's a free, open source, portable app that will let you globally set your preferred folder view defaults, including whatever column(s) you want to sort by.